# 2Checkout Authorization Fails since June

Tags: wordpress, payment-gateway, payment-processing, 2checkout

From the beginning of this (June 2018) month most of my clients can not pay with 2Checkout by card, everything was OK before.

I begin collecting the responses, they are always the same:

```
"validationErrors":null,
"exception":{
    "errorMsg":"Authorization Failed",
    "httpStatus":"400",
    "exception":false,
    "errorCode":"600"
},"response":null
```

I have no idea what is going on, I tried to contact their support team, but everything they said, that everything should work, but actually it doesn't!

I use API to process payments. The website code haven't changed since that time.

The request to 2CO looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [method] => POST
    [timeout] => 45
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [Accept] => application/json
            [Content-Type] => application/json
        )

    [body] => {
        "sellerId":"my seller id",
        "privateKey":"my private key",
        "merchantOrderId":just a random number,
        "token":"token received from 2CO",
        "currency":"USD",
        "total":"130.00",
        "billingAddr":{
            "name":"name from debit/credit card here",
            "addrLine1":"customer address here",
            "addrLine2":"",
            "city":"customer city here",
            "state":"",
            "zipCode":"",
            "country":"MX",
            "email":"customer email here"
        },
        "lineItems":[{
            "name":"product name here",
            "price":"130.00",
            "type":"product",
            "quantity":"1"
            }]
        }
)
```

Above is the example for a Mexico customer, so, addrLine2, state and zipCode are not required.

Thanks for help in advance!